# onSaveInstanceState not working

Tags: android, google-maps, savestate

I am trying to save the type of map that the user selected through the menu so the type of map remains even if the device will be rotated or the activity will be suspended for a few moments. This is what I did but it doesn't seem to work. Please can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
 private int mapTypeSelected;

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     if (savedInstanceState == null){
            mapTypeSelected = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL;
        } else {
            mapTypeSelected = savedInstanceState.getInt("the_map_type",GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
               }
      }
```

My main menu has more choices but I added here only the relevant ones for the map type:

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.change_map_type:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Change map type", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.map_type_normal:
            mapTypeSelected = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL;
            mMap.setMapType(mapTypeSelected);
            return true;
        case R.id.map_type_satellite:
            mapTypeSelected = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE;
            mMap.setMapType(mapTypeSelected);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

           }

}
```

Then at the end of my activity I added this two:

```
   @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("the_map_type", mapTypeSelected);

}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.get("the_map_type");

}
```

I am sure that is something stupid that I am doing wrong but I cannot seem to see what. There is no error and everything is working fine just that on rotation the map type changes always to normal. 
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: That is not the reason. This was a copy mistake that I made. Now it is corrected.

Comment: You are not setting map type outside the `onOptionsItemSelected` ... you may do it right after you obtain `mMap` instance

Comment: Can you be a little more explicit?

Comment: well, yes, onSaveInstanceState is working but you never use the data saved there ... (yes, you obtain it in `onCreate` to a variable but never use it)

Comment: I knew it was a stupid mistake but I didn't imagine it was that stupid:-) Thanks ! How can I vote your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
private int mMapType;
private boolean mRestoreMap;

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("the_map_type", mMap.getMapType());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    mMapType = savedInstanceState.getInt("the_map_type", -1);
    mRestoreMap = (mMapType != -1);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    mMap = map;

    if(mRestoreMap){
        mMap.setMapType(mMapType);
    }

}
```

Comment: I already have the answer. All I had to do is add mMap.setMapType(mapTypeSelected); in the onMapReady

Comment: Ohh i see now too :)